# GRUB doesn't show all OS's

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub2, gentoo

I am on Arch currently and have Gentoo in a separate partition. `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` (on Arch) returns:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux-zen
Found initrd image: /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux-zen.img
Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot: initramfs-linux-zen-fallback.img
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Found Gentoo/Linux on /dev/nvme0n1p9
done
```

However there is no entry for Gentoo in the boot menu, while there is one for Windows. There is no Gentoo entry in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` too. Am I missing something here?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to ensure that the gentoo partition is actually mounted when running `grub-mkconfig`. Output from the following tools are helpful in determining this:

- `lsblk`
- `mount`
- `df`

If you need to dig deeper, tail the log journal in one terminal window while running os-prober as root in another.

Window 1: `sudo journalctl -fn0`

Window 2: `sudo os-prober`

The `grub-mkconfig` command uses the os-prober utility to find your other operating systems and os-prober logs to the journal on Arch, so that'll provide all of the information that you'd need to find out exactly why it's not finding gentoo as long as the partition is actually mounted.

Comment: Even when it was not mounted, os-prober and grub-mkconfig both had Gentoo in the output. And after mounting it, there is no change. grub.cfg doesn't change.

Comment: Can you post the logs that are produced when running os-prober?

Comment: Here http://codepad.org/zFCNfwoK. BTW, ```adelie``` is my hostname and ```kon5oul``` my username.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed arch on a drive other than the drive on whose partition gentoo is installed then only grub-install /dev/sdX (X is the drive number) will obviously not find gentoo.

Read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/325631/how-to-install-grub-on-multiple-disks) ;basically you have to grub-install multiple drives.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the http://codepad.org/zFCNfwoK output mentioned in the comments...

`os-prober` finds Gentoo on `/dev/nvme0n1p9`, but apparently then the next step is `linux-boot-prober`. It will run the test scripts located in `/usr/lib/linux-boot-probes`.

Looks like `/usr/lib/linux-boot-probes/mounted/90fallback` should be able to detect the kernel and initramfs of Gentoo if they are located in either the root directory or the `boot` sub-directory of `/dev/nvme0n1p9` filesystem, assuming that filesystem type is something GRUB can read. But Gentoo can be installed on UEFI in several possible ways, and some of them will place the kernel+initramfs onto the EFI System Partition, which would be `/dev/nvme0n1p1` in your case.

At least on my Debian 10, it looks like `os-prober` might need updates to cover more UEFI installation cases.

Please run `efibootmgr -v`. Has Gentoo generated a NVRAM boot entry for itself? It could be used to find out where Gentoo's kernel (or bootloader, if it uses one instead of relying on the EFI stub in the kernel) is located.

(An idea: Someone might write a script for `os-prober` to run on UEFI systems, that would step through all the NVRAM-registered bootloaders and use `file` to find out if the pointed-to boot file looks like a Linux kernel. That should cover quite a lot of the cases where the kernel's EFI stub is used instead of a separate bootloader.)

Comment: ```efibootmgr -v``` returns termbin.com/oo9f. The ```GRUB2``` is the GRUB I have installed separately on Gentoo today.